# Excel VBA to find, replace epoch timestamp with date in string

Tags: excel, regex, vba, epoch

and thanks in advance for any help you can offer. I've been banging around user forums for days and am totally stumped. (Also, I'm a total newbie who can barely spell "VBA", but I'm trying!)

I have an Excel spreadsheet with cells containing threads of user comments. Each comment is preceded by a 10-digit epoch time stamp. The cells look like this:

> <[1486481641]>-User 1: I like pie.  <[1486489862]>-User 2: I like
> cake. <[1486490937]>-User 1: Pie is better than cake.

I would like a macro that finds all epoch timestamps in each cell and replaces them with a human-readable date & time.

I have a function that will convert an epoch string to Excel time (but the timestamp needs to be the only data in the cell, and it puts the date/time in an adjacent cell) and another macro that finds a regEx string and replaces it with something else. I haven't the foggiest idea how to combine them.

My epoch conversion function looks like this:

```
Function ux2pst(uts)
ux2pst = Format(DateAdd("s", uts, "12/31/1969 16:00:00"), "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM")
End Function
```

And my regEx find/replace should like something like this, but I don't know how to include the conversion code in the regEx.Replace statement:

```
Sub replaceEpoch()
Dim regEx As Object
Dim r As Range, rT As Range

Set r = Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regEx.Pattern = "\d{10}"
regEx.Global = True

For Each rT In r
    If rT.Value <> "" Then rT.Value = regEx.Replace(rT.Value, "CONVERTED DATE-TIME??")
Next rT
    
End Sub
```

I've tried a few different things, but all have been spectacular failures. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all the matches of the `epoch` time the regular expression finds, pass them to the function to ux2pst and replace them with the result.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub replaceEpoch()
Dim regEx As Object
Dim r As Range, rT As Range
Dim mtch As Object

    Set r = Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regEx.Pattern = "\d{10}"
    regEx.Global = True

    For Each rT In r
        If rT.Value <> "" Then
            For Each mtch In regEx.Execute(rT.Value)
                rT.Value = Replace(rT.Value, mtch, ux2pst(mtch))
            Next mtch
        End If
    Next rT

End Sub

Function ux2pst(uts)
    ux2pst = Format(DateAdd("s", uts, "12/31/1969 16:00:00"), "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM")
End Function
```